# How to skip a specifc line in a file?

Tags: python

[image]I am trying to write every line into a new file except for the ones that have H in there in this particular space. I really cant figure out why this isnt working and it replicates the whole file1. 
I am trying to get character 13, which my code is actually doing so no need to suggest this. The problem must be somewhere after.

Thank you

```
import fileinput
import sys

f1 = open('file1', 'r')
f2 = open('file2', 'w')
for line in f1:
    if len(line) > 50 and line[13] != 'H':
        f2.write(line)
    else:
        continue

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

File example:

Comment: Please post a sample of your file and your desired output from that sample.

Comment: Can you give an example of your input file and example lines in that file you would like to skip?

Comment: What do you mean is "replicates" file1? Can state exactly what is wrong?

Comment: It just copies it all, not skipping the lines I want to be skipped.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you positive that "H" is in bucket 13? Perhaps this is just off by one. I'm assuming the file is using spaces and not tabs. One way to test this is to, in your if statement, `print(line[13)` to see what it thinks is there. This would be easier if you just posted a coded sample instead of a screenshot, so people could simply copy/paste to reproduce.

Comment: `line[13]` is the 14th character. You're not parsing the column structure of your input, and you're not accessing the 13th column.

Comment: `line[13]` is *character* 13, not *column* 13 (which is wrong anyway). If you want to check a specific column you can use `line.split()[11]`.

Comment: So I am trying to get character 13, which my code is actually doing. The problem must be somewhere after. user2357112: I dont want to access column 13, I want character 14, that is correct

Comment: Can you post a few lines of your actual data and not a picture of it?

Comment: ATOM    442  O   THR D 519      53.454  28.382 -31.426  1.00115.21           O  
ATOM      0  H   THR D 519      54.651  26.608 -30.680  1.00115.21           H   new  
ATOM      0  HA  THR D 519      56.509  28.420 -31.365  1.00115.21           H   new  
ATOM      0  HB  THR D 519      56.971  26.715 -32.825  1.00115.21           H   new  
ATOM      0  HG1 THR D 519      56.645  28.848 -33.660  1.00115.21           H   new  
ATOM      0 HG21 THR D 519      55.251  25.748 -34.137  1.00115.21           H   new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that `H` is always proceeded by another entry:

```
import fileinput
import sys

f1 = open('file1', 'r')
f2 = open('file2', 'w')
for line in f1:
    temp = line.split()
    if len(temp) > 2:
        if temp[-2] != 'H':
            f2.write(line)
    else:
        f2.write(line)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

It splits each line and checks if the next-to-last element is `H`.

If the line is shorter than 2 elements it skips it and just writes it to the file.

Your previous program actually works in the sense that it does not print lines that contain `H` in `line[13]`, but as mentioned in the comments to your question, the `H` you're looking for is shifted in some rows due to other data. So some of the lines with hydrogens are removed, ones with `H` in `line[13]`, while the others are written in the output file.

Comment: Thank you. When I try to run this I get this:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "removeHydrogens.py", line 7, in <module>
    if line.split()[-2] !='H': IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: ATOM    263  C   PRO D 493      44.901  12.877 -35.260  1.00503.07           C  
ATOM    264  O   PRO D 493      44.333  13.810 -34.693  1.00503.07           O  
ATOM      0  HA  PRO D 493      45.449  10.978 -34.586  1.00503.07           H   new  
ATOM      0  HB2 PRO D 493      43.192  11.390 -36.270  1.00503.07           H   new  
ATOM      0  HB3 PRO D 493      43.542   9.893 -36.005  1.00503.07           H   new                                This doesnt look like the right format. I am trying to format. Is there a way to attach a file?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9sxvj4avfas0x2f/converted_4MWF_IVAT_rich.pdb?dl=0     Hopefully this will work

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought that the way I wrote it it would copy any line except for the ones that doesnt have the H in. Can you explain to me why wont this work?

Comment: Why does it not write the END and the TER lines?

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: The `else: continue` is redundant in this case.

Comment: @Mark Ransom I left it only because the OP had it (clarified it previously in the answer). I'll remove it.